Energy required for reflection

Blockquote

I was thinking about medieval combat and using shields to block, say, a sword stroke. My intuition says that deflecting the strike would be far better than absorbing it, but when I ran the numbers, it wasn't obvious that it was better.
The model I'm using (immovable barrier, elastic collisions) is very "spherical chicken" I know, but I'm just trying to get 1st-order realism.

As shown above, the deflection angle is θ, and the bounced object (e.g. sword) has the same energy and velocity as it had coming in.
If we decompose the incoming kinetic energy, it looks like the following-

If the incoming energy is 1, then to elastically bounce the object, the barrier has to apply 2cos(θ) energy to the object. 1cos(θ) to counteract the incoming vector, and another 1cos(θ) to elastically bounce it. The amount of energy required to elastically deflect the object is shown below-

This graph suggests that the energy required to deflect the object doesn't become less than the energy to simply absorb the energy, which is 1, until the deflection angle is more than 60 degrees.
My questions are:

Do I have this right? Is there something I'm missing?

Obviously things would change if I allowed collisions to be non-elastic. In that case I have a question about conservation of energy. In the case of a shield/sword, presumably the lost energy becomes heat, sound, etc. Let's say a magnetic field is used to deflect the object instead. Can the "bounced" object have less energy than the incoming object? If so, where does the energy go?



What you call energy looks a lot like momentum to me. You cannot decompose the kinetic energy like you do (observe that $\sin \theta + \cos\theta \neq 1$, this means that your component energies do not sum back to the full energy), but you can decompose momentum that way. The "relative energy" that you plot then becomes impulse needed to change the momentum of the incoming object. This is the "kick" you feel when someone hits the shield you hold.
You also have the right conclusion that requiring elastic reflection (i.e. one that conserves kinetic energy) is "too expensive" in the sense that the impulse is twice that than what would be needed if you were to just absorb the impact (bring the normal component of object's momentum to zero while leaving the tangential component unchanged).
If you absorb the normal component of the momentum then the kinetic energy is indeed not conserved - part of it gets converted to heat. If the shield were to be immovable then this would mean some deformation of the incoming object, sound etc. But usually the shield moves a bit back - the object pushes it against a force that resists the movement - the object does some work and that is where the kinetic energy goes - it is absorbed by the muscles in the arm holding the shield (a little bit still goes into sound and deformation).
So in summary you want to position yourself and the shield so that $\theta$ is quite large and then you absorb whatever momentum is headed your way (i. e. perpendicular to the shield). This will always be "better" (smaller impulse and absorbed energy) than completely stopping the incoming object.
Regarding the magnetic shields - total energy still needs to be conserved so the considerations would be the same as above. If the bounced object ends up with less energy then the shield and its holder have the rest.
